# updating a word document using phpword but the format is changing

Tags: phpword

My word doc is in the following format

`The Capital of this Partnership shall be the sum of Rs ______________/- (Rupees ____________________________________ Only) which shall be contributed by the Parties in following proportion:
a.  First Party: Rs ____________ /-
b.  Second Party: Rs _____________/-
c.  Third Party: Rs _______________/-`

I have edited my word doc in the following format for phpword `setValue` method to work

`The Capital of this Partnership shall be the sum of Rs $(value1)/- (Rupees $(value2) Only) which shall be contributed by the Parties in following proportion:
a.  First Party: Rs $(value3) /-
b.  Second Party: Rs $(value4)/-
c.  Third Party: Rs $(value5)/-`

Written the following php code to replace the words in the document

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('Template.docx');
$document->setValue('Value1', '100');
$document->setValue('Value2', 'hundred');
$document->setValue('Value3', '50');
$document->setValue('Value4', '25');
$document->setValue('Value5', '25');
$document->save('CAPITAL.docx');
?>
```

the word document is being saved and changes are being made but the formatting of the document is changing like

`The Capital of this Partnership shall be the sum of Rs 100/- (Rupees hundred Only) which shall be contributed by the Parties in following proportion:
a.  First Party: Rs 50/-
b.  Second Party: Rs 25/-
c.  Third Party: Rs 25/-`

I want all the words to remain in their place and also the length of the input should be the same (eg `____________/-`  should be `50        /-`)

Comment: This seems more of a Word "issue". `100` has fewer letters than its placeholder `$(value1)`, so it is common sense that the words that follow after it in the document are not in the same place as in the template. Format your Word template so that its layout remains unchanged despite the length of the values.

Comment: What if someone enters 10000000000?

Comment: You will need to truncate values if you want to maintain formatting. Maybe show some kind of tooltip/note in Word containing the full value?

Comment: Basically try defining text placeholders in Word with minimum and maximum text length being equal. Check https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-Word-c8466a9a-525a-4ba4-8e57-ed24101f4291